# Drop all rows of a dataframe where the index%number == 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple usecase to drop all rows where the index%number== 0, for me numebr is 14. There are explainations for multiindex dataframes which I'm not getting.
I need something like

```
df.drop(df.index%14 == 0)
```

Comment: ``df[~(df.index % 14 == 0)]`` ?

Comment: I can upvote and accept this if you post the same as an answer :)